# How to set up Github Webhook on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: webhooks, strapi, github-webhook

I'm following the deployment guide of AWS which can be found [here](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/amazon-aws.html). I've made it up to the point where we set up a Webhook. I'm using commands below to enable and start the webhook as it's stated in the documentation.

```
sudo systemctl enable webhook.service
sudo systemctl start webhook
```

However when I use `sudo systemctl status webhook` to check the status of the webhook, I get the following output that indicates there's an error.

> ● webhook.service - Github webhook Loaded: loaded
> (/etc/systemd/system/webhook.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-06-29 14:21:43 UTC;
> 29s ago Process: 26849 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nodejs
> /home/ubuntu/NodeWebHooks/webhook.js (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
> Main PID: 26849 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Jun 29 14:21:42 ip-172-31-41-113 systemd[1](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/amazon-aws.html): webhook.service: Main
> process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Jun 29 14:21:42
> ip-172-31-41-113 systemd[1](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/amazon-aws.html): webhook.service: Failed with result
> 'exit-code'. Jun 29 14:21:43 ip-172-31-41-113 systemd[1](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/amazon-aws.html):
> webhook.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart. Jun
> 29 14:21:43 ip-172-31-41-113 systemd[1](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/amazon-aws.html): webhook.service: Scheduled
> restart job, restart counter is at 5. Jun 29 14:21:43 ip-172-31-41-113
> systemd[1](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/amazon-aws.html): Stopped Github webhook. Jun 29 14:21:43 ip-172-31-41-113
> systemd[1](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/amazon-aws.html): webhook.service: Start request repeated too quickly. Jun
> 29 14:21:43 ip-172-31-41-113 systemd[1](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/amazon-aws.html): webhook.service: Failed with
> result 'exit-code'. Jun 29 14:21:43 ip-172-31-41-113 systemd[1](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/amazon-aws.html):
> Failed to start Github webhook.

What could be wrong with this setup?

System

Node.js version: v12.18.1

NPM version: 6.14.5

Strapi version: 3.0.1

Database: PostgreSQL

Operating system: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

try this one. quite simple and it works

https://ep.gnt.md/index.php/how-to-automatically-deploy-from-github-to-server-using-webhook/